# ERROR (no such process) returned when I'm hit sudo supervisorctl status

Tags: laravel, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, supervisord, laravel-queue

I had faced the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 (web server: apache2).

Returned an error ": ERROR (no such process)"

Answer (score 0):

There is no process running in your supervisor.
If you have any scheduler or queue jobs then you can create a process in the supervisor.

1. to create a process for the supervisor

   `sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/process_name.conf`

you can change the process_name.conf to your process name.

2 . Enter the process roles in the opened window.
here I'm listing an example

```
    [program:queue-worker]

    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d

    command= your process    
    autostart=true

    autorestart=true

    user=root

    numprocs=8

    redirect_stderr=true

    stdout_logfile=/var/www/path_to_project/storage/logs/notification_out.log
    stderr_logfile= /var/www/path_to_project/storage/logs/notification_err.log
```

There is to logs created by the supervisor `stdout_logfile` and `stderr_logfile` to monitor your process

and you can change the program **queue-worker** to any process name

3. Enter the command to reread supervisor.

   `sudo supervisorctl reread`
4. Enter the command to update the supervisor.

   `sudo supervisorctl update`
5. Enter the command to start the supervisor.

   `sudo supervisorctl start:queue-worker`

the **queue-worker** is your program name

here is the detailed doc.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps